# How do I install the boost library to my MinGW compiler?

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I'm compiling from the command line using g++ on a Windows MinGW installation.  How do I get boost...conceptually or if it is easy...what do I need to download and install?

Comment: Prepare for great pain and suffering.

Comment: Did you not read the Boost installation instructions? Which parts are you struggling with?

Comment: If you are flexible about what compiler you can use, it's significantly easier to install Boost for Visual C++, as BoostPro provides binaries and an installer: http://www.boostpro.com/download/. If you must use MinGW, there are a couple options. 1 - Use STL's mingw/gcc distribution, which comes with a prebuilt Boost 1.47.0 and is neatly packaged (http://nuwen.net/mingw.html). STL works on the Visual Studio software at Microsoft. 2 - Download the source code for boost from boost.org, and follow these instructions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

Comment: I'll try nuwen despite the web site...seriously how could something so useful...be on this web-site...shouldn't this be on sourceforge.net or similar?

Comment: @ChrisAaker: Because that's Stephan T. Lavavej's web-site.  And he's a boss.  See his videos on Channel 9. http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/stephan-t-lavavej

Comment: This may be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181832/install-boost-on-windows-with-codeblocks/14186795#14186795

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for future reference for anybody coming to this page try this website,
http://nuwen.net/mingw.html

They have done all the hard work so you don't have to. The most recent distribution on this page has boost 1_52_0 (which is the latest version on the boost website as I'm writing this) including the separately compiled libraries (e.g. boost thread, boost regex etc) which I beleive you're asking for

Comment: Thank you. Compared to Mac/FreeBSD/Linux boost is such a pain to compile and install.

Answer (score 18):

I spent hours searching for a good solution for Boost 1.54. If you already have MinGW and you're just looking for instructions on compiling the binary boost libraries, try this:

1. From your boost_X_XX_X directory, go to

   ```
   .\tools\build\src\engine
   ```

   and type:

   ```
   build.bat mingw
   ```
2. This will create a folder called `bin.ntx86` or `bin.ntx86_64` depending on your architecture. Add this directory to your PATH environment variable.
3. Return to your boost_X_XX_X directory and type:

   ```
   bjam toolset=gcc
   ```

This worked for me on my system. I'd be interested to know if other systems have trouble with these instructions.

Comment: This no longer works. There is no v2 directory. There is `./tools/build/src/engine.bat` though. Haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 12):

However there would have been a simpler, yet identical way; your steps until the bjam call are automatically done by bootstrap.bat:

```
C:\boost_1_52_0> bootstrap.bat mingw
Building Boost.Build engine 
...
C:\boost_1_52_0> b2 toolset=gcc
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13257930/2171309

Comment: This works, the `mingw` target however does not exist anymore. Just use the `gcc` target,

Answer (score 2):

Thanx to Neal Kruis. This worked for me. I have Qt 5.4 with mingw 4.9 installed. I downloaded boost 1.59. Go to "...\boost_1_59_0\tools\build\src\engine\" folder

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\mingw491_32\bin
build.bat mingw
```

go to "...\boost_1_59_0\" folder, change boost path accordingly

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\boost_1_59_0\tools\build\src\engine\bin.ntx86
bjam toolset=gcc
```