# fix: too many sections (52187) - Cmake, Qmake

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, mingw, qmake

I need to compile a C++ program on Windows using the CLion IDE with `CMake` and Qt Creator with `QMake`.
On Linux, I do not get any problems at all.
On Windows, I wanted to use the `MinGW` compiler. My source code relies on `boost`. Therefore, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847454/how-do-i-install-the-boost-library-to-my-mingw-compiler) question, I was installing the compiler from the [MinGW Distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

So far so good. Now, during the compilation process I get the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/as.exe: CMakeFiles\[...]: too many sections (52187)
C:\Users\MATTHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2TyXHu.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\MATTHI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2TyXHu.s: Fatal error: can't write 231 bytes to section .text of CMakeFiles\[...]: 'file too big'
```

after some research, ([here](https://digitalkarabela.com/mingw-w64-how-to-fix-file-too-big-too-many-sections/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596876/object-file-has-too-many-sections)) I found out that heavy templating might be the reason for this issue... However, I do not do any templating at all, but I'm including the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) libraries that might cause the issue.

In any case, I need to fix this and the proposed solution is to add the following flags to my compiler:
`-Wa,-mbig-obj`.

My question now is: how can I do this in my IDE (CLion or QtCreator) or in my `CMakeLists.txt` (CMake) and/or `myProject.pro` (QMake) files?

Comment: For cmake you could use the `target_compile_options()` command, but you should probably check, if the compiler used is one you know supports the options.

Comment: Did you find a solution since then? I have the exact same problem, on windows/CMake/QtCreator/Eigen